# Code won't run, getting stuck at while loop

Tags: c++

When I try to run the program visual studio code gets stuck at the while look and won't run the code. When copy and pasting the code to an online compiler the code runs. Also I can't use vectors or reverse from the library.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream> 
#include <ctime>


using namespace std;

void reverse(double* a, int size)
{
    double* left = a;
    double* right = a + size - 1;
    while (left < right)
    {
        double temp = *left;
        *left++ = *right;
        *right-- = temp;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int size = 0;
    float input;
    double* a = new double[size];
    int capacity = 10;
    cout << "Please enter the values: ";
    while (cin >> input)
    {
        if (cin.fail())
        {
            cin.clear();
        }
        if (size == capacity) {
            capacity *= 2;
        }
        a[size++] = input;
        if (size == capacity)
        {
            capacity *= 2;
            double* b = new double[capacity];
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                b[i] = a[i];
            }
            delete[] a;
            a = b;
        }
    }
    cout << "The input values are: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i];
        if (i < size - 1)
            cout << ", ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    reverse(a, size);

    cout << "The reversed values are: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
        if (i < size - 1)
            cout << ", ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I tried using a break command it didn't work. I'm expecting the code to run the function and take in all the inputs and print the array and its reverse

Comment: PSA: Use `std::vector<double>` instead of `new[]`. These will resize automatically when you use `push_back` and such. There is no need to manually allocate and juggle allocations here. These also afford tools like [`std::reverse`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse).

Comment: `double* a = new double[size];` allocates space for 0 items. `a[size++] = input;` tries to store something where there is no space for it It seems you want to allocate for `capacity` items, not `size`.

Comment: If your loop is "stuck" it's probably because you haven't sent an end-of-file and it's waiting for more input.

Comment: Use the debugger to step through the code to find your logic error. If you don't know how to use a debugger, now is an excellent time to start learning. There is no better tool available in a programmer's toolbox than the debugger for tracing code execution and finding logic errors.

Comment: *Also I can't use vectors or reverse from the library* --  vectors and algorithms have officially been part of C++ for 25 years now.  Stupid restrictions like "do not use vector or algorithms" is a big reason why many new programmers drop learning C++, and go to python, Java, C#, etc.

Comment: @RetiredNinja and from that point on, everything is Undefined Behavior.  The fact that it ran on an online compiler means nothing.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie do you believe there's no value in teaching people how something like std::vector works under the covers?

Comment: Sure there is value in teaching it.  If it is being taught, teach it in a way where there is something to be learned, and not simply throw a beginner to the wolves, and have them come up with a tangled mess of `new[]` and `delete[]` calls.

Answer (score -1):

can you check if this is the answer you wanted, I made the input variable integer type where you were using float/double type, I thought it is the problem, also you did not update the input in the while loop so I used `while(input--)` . These are the changes I have made I do not know if this is the answer you wanted. I added the comment where I made changes to the code. Hope it is helpful.

````
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream> 
#include <ctime>


using namespace std;

void reverse(double* a, int size)
{
   double* left = a;
   double* right = a + size - 1;
   while (left < right)
   {
       double temp = *left;
       *left++ = *right;
       *right-- = temp;
   }
}

int main()
{
   int size = 0;
   int input; // I made input variable integer type you were using float type
   double* a = new double[size];
   int capacity = 10;
   cout << "Please enter the values: ";
   cin >> input ; // took the value of the input variable here
   while (input--) // you did not decrement the input variable
   {
       if (cin.fail())
       {
           cin.clear();
       }
       if (size == capacity) {
           capacity *= 2;
       }
       a[size++] = input;
       if (size == capacity)
       {
           capacity *= 2;
           double* b = new double[capacity];
           for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
           {
               b[i] = a[i];
           }
           delete[] a;
           a = b;
       }
   }
   cout << "The input values are: ";
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
       cout << a[i];
       if (i < size - 1)
           cout << ", ";
   }
   cout << endl;

   reverse(a, size);

   cout << "The reversed values are: ";
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
       cout << a[i] << " ";
       if (i < size - 1)
           cout << ", ";
   }
   cout << endl;

   return 0;
}```
````

Comment: Can you include in your answer some commentary about what changes you made to the code and why?  A simple code dump with no explanation is likely to get downvoted.

Comment: Please note that you misinterpreted the idiom `while (cin >> input) {...}`. The OP is trying to read floating-point numbers (`input` is `float`, while it should be `double`, in their code) and put them into a dynamically allocated array of `double`s. The loop should stop when a reading error or EOF occurred.